# Xcode8 ios10 - Webviewer Won't Load The URL?

Tags: xcode, ios10

I'm trying to make a Webviewer in iOS 10 using Xcode 8. It won't load up my URL I'm trying to view however; if I change the

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Webview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = NSURL(string: "htpps://shoalshousehunter.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)

        Webview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```